# Script Out Server Properties and Database Properties

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

MSSQL 2014

If possible, can someone provide the tsql to extract the settings from the pages of Server Properties and Database Properties?

[image: Database_Properties]
[image: Server_Properties]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [DATABASEPROPERTY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176049(v=sql.105).aspx) and [SERVERPROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql).

Just list them in a `SELECT` statement like:

```
SELECT 
 [Service_Name]                 = @@SERVICENAME
,[Server Name]                  = SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')
,[Physical_Net_BIOS_Name]       = SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')
,[Edition]                      = SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
,[Product_Version]              = SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')
,[Product_Update_Reference]     = SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateReference')
,[Resource_Last_Update_Date]    = SERVERPROPERTY('ResourceLastUpdateDateTime')
,[Process_ID]                   = SERVERPROPERTY('ProcessID')
,[Collation]                    = SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
,[CLR_Version]                  = SERVERPROPERTY('BuildClrVersion')
,[Is_Clustered]                 = SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') 
,[Is_FullText_Installed]        = SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled') 
,[Is_Integrated_Security_Only]  = SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')
,[File_Stream_Configured_Level] = SERVERPROPERTY('FilestreamConfiguredLevel')
,[Is_HA_DR_Enabled]             = SERVERPROPERTY('IsHadrEnabled') 
,[HA_DR_Manager_Status]         = SERVERPROPERTY('HadrManagerStatus')
,[Default_Data_Path]            = SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath')
,[Default_Log_Path]             = SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath')
```

And add/delete any property you need.

Comment: Thanks.  It would be nice if there was a way to dynamically select all the options.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across your old post. I wrote this for DATABASEPROPERTYEX since I need to do the same:

```sql
DECLARE @DB SYSNAME = 'adventureworks'
SELECT 'Collation' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'Collation') as Value UNION
SELECT 'ComparisonStyle' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'ComparisonStyle') as Value UNION
SELECT 'Edition' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'Edition') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsAnsiNullDefault' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsAnsiNullDefault') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsAnsiNullsEnabled' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsAnsiNullsEnabled') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsAnsiPaddingEnabled' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsAnsiPaddingEnabled') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsAnsiWarningsEnabled' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsAnsiWarningsEnabled') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsArithmeticAbortEnabled' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsArithmeticAbortEnabled') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsAutoClose' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsAutoClose') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsAutoCreateStatistics' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsAutoCreateStatistics') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsAutoCreateStatisticsIncremental' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsAutoCreateStatisticsIncremental') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsAutoShrink' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsAutoShrink') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsAutoUpdateStatistics' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsAutoUpdateStatistics') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsClone' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsClone') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsCloseCursorsOnCommitEnabled' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsCloseCursorsOnCommitEnabled') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsFulltextEnabled' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsFulltextEnabled') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsInStandBy' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsInStandBy') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsLocalCursorsDefault' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsLocalCursorsDefault') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsMemoryOptimizedElevateToSnapshotEnabled' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsMemoryOptimizedElevateToSnapshotEnabled') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsMergePublished' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsMergePublished') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsNullConcat' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsNullConcat') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsNumericRoundAbortEnabled' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsNumericRoundAbortEnabled') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsParameterizationForced' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsParameterizationForced') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsQuotedIdentifiersEnabled' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsQuotedIdentifiersEnabled') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsPublished' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsPublished') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsRecursiveTriggersEnabled' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsRecursiveTriggersEnabled') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsSubscribed' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsSubscribed') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsSyncWithBackup' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsSyncWithBackup') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsTornPageDetectionEnabled' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsTornPageDetectionEnabled') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsVerifiedClone' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsVerifiedClone') as Value UNION
SELECT 'IsXTPSupported' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'IsXTPSupported') as Value UNION
SELECT 'LastGoodCheckDbTime' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'LastGoodCheckDbTime') as Value UNION
SELECT 'LCID' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'LCID') as Value UNION
SELECT 'MaxSizeInBytes' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'MaxSizeInBytes') as Value UNION
SELECT 'Recovery' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'Recovery') as Value UNION
SELECT 'ServiceObjective' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'ServiceObjective') as Value UNION
SELECT 'ServiceObjectiveId' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'ServiceObjectiveId') as Value UNION
SELECT 'SQLSortOrder' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'SQLSortOrder') as Value UNION
SELECT 'Status' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'Status') as Value UNION
SELECT 'Updateability' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'Updateability') as Value UNION
SELECT 'UserAccess' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'UserAccess') as Value UNION
SELECT 'Version' as Property, DATABASEPROPERTYEX (@DB, 'Version') as Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @dbname varchar(max)='adventureworks2016ctp3' 
select 'name' as feature, cast(name as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname 
union select 'database_id', cast(database_id as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname 
union select 'source_database_id', cast(source_database_id as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'owner_sid', cast(user_name(owner_sid) as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'create_date', cast(create_date as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'compatibility_level', cast(compatibility_level as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'collation_name', cast(collation_name as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname 
union select 'user_access', cast(user_access as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname 
union select 'user_access_desc', cast(user_access_desc as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname 
union select 'is_read_only', cast(is_read_only as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_auto_close_on', cast(is_auto_close_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_auto_shrink_on', cast(is_auto_shrink_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'state', cast(state as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'state_desc', cast(state_desc as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_in_standby', cast(is_in_standby as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_cleanly_shutdown', cast(is_cleanly_shutdown as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_supplemental_logging_enabled', cast(is_supplemental_logging_enabled as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'snapshot_isolation_state', cast(snapshot_isolation_state as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'snapshot_isolation_state_desc', cast(snapshot_isolation_state_desc as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_read_committed_snapshot_on', cast(is_read_committed_snapshot_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'recovery_model', cast(recovery_model as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'recovery_model_desc', cast(recovery_model_desc as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'page_verify_option', cast(page_verify_option as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'page_verify_option_desc', cast(page_verify_option_desc as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_auto_create_stats_on', cast(is_auto_create_stats_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_auto_create_stats_incremental_on', cast(is_auto_create_stats_incremental_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_auto_update_stats_on', cast(is_auto_update_stats_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_auto_update_stats_async_on', cast(is_auto_update_stats_async_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_ansi_null_default_on', cast(is_ansi_null_default_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_ansi_nulls_on', cast(is_ansi_nulls_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_ansi_padding_on', cast(is_ansi_padding_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_ansi_warnings_on', cast(is_ansi_warnings_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_arithabort_on', cast(is_arithabort_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_concat_null_yields_null_on', cast(is_concat_null_yields_null_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_numeric_roundabort_on', cast(is_numeric_roundabort_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_quoted_identifier_on', cast(is_quoted_identifier_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_recursive_triggers_on', cast(is_recursive_triggers_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_cursor_close_on_commit_on', cast(is_cursor_close_on_commit_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_local_cursor_default', cast(is_local_cursor_default as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_fulltext_enabled', cast(is_fulltext_enabled as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_trustworthy_on', cast(is_trustworthy_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_db_chaining_on', cast(is_db_chaining_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_parameterization_forced', cast(is_parameterization_forced as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_master_key_encrypted_by_server', cast(is_master_key_encrypted_by_server as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_query_store_on', cast(is_query_store_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_published', cast(is_published as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_subscribed', cast(is_subscribed as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_merge_published', cast(is_merge_published as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_distributor', cast(is_distributor as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_sync_with_backup', cast(is_sync_with_backup as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'service_broker_guid', cast(service_broker_guid as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_broker_enabled', cast(is_broker_enabled as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'log_reuse_wait', cast(log_reuse_wait as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'log_reuse_wait_desc', cast(log_reuse_wait_desc as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_date_correlation_on', cast(is_date_correlation_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_cdc_enabled', cast(is_cdc_enabled as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_encrypted', cast(is_encrypted as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_honor_broker_priority_on', cast(is_honor_broker_priority_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'replica_id', cast(replica_id as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'group_database_id', cast(group_database_id as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'resource_pool_id', cast(resource_pool_id as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'default_language_lcid', cast(default_language_lcid as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'default_language_name', cast(default_language_name as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'default_fulltext_language_lcid', cast(default_fulltext_language_lcid as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'default_fulltext_language_name', cast(default_fulltext_language_name as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_nested_triggers_on', cast(is_nested_triggers_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_transform_noise_words_on', cast(is_transform_noise_words_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'two_digit_year_cutoff', cast(two_digit_year_cutoff as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'containment', cast(containment as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'containment_desc', cast(containment_desc as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'target_recovery_time_in_seconds', cast(target_recovery_time_in_seconds as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'delayed_durability', cast(delayed_durability as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'delayed_durability_desc', cast(delayed_durability_desc as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_memory_optimized_elevate_to_snapshot_on', cast(is_memory_optimized_elevate_to_snapshot_on as varchar(60)) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_federation_member', cast(is_federation_member as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_remote_data_archive_enabled', cast(is_remote_data_archive_enabled as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_mixed_page_allocation_on', cast(is_mixed_page_allocation_on as sql_variant) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
union select 'is_temporal_history_retention_enabled', cast(is_temporal_history_retention_enabled as varchar(70)) as " value" from sys.databases where name=@dbname
```

Comment: wrote this based on the sys.databases table