# How to get all the database properties using DATABASEPROPERTYEX()?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't have an SQL Server on my computer and was wondering if I this will work:

```sql
Select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DB_name', *);
```

or do I have to write every property?

Comment: `I don't have an SQL Server` - but you do have [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/databasepropertyex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) which reads, *"`DATABASEPROPERTYEX` returns only one property setting at a time. To display multiple property settings, use the `sys.databases` catalog view."*.

Comment: Somebody [already did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53559856/11647724) what you need to do :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The [documentation's remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/databasepropertyex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) explicitly says:

> DATABASEPROPERTYEX returns only one property setting at a time. To display multiple property settings, use the [sys.databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) catalog view.

Answer (score 0):

All property names will have to be explicitly written one way or another. This is how I'd do it:

```
select ss.value as PropName, DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DB_name',ss.value) as PropValue
from string_split(
'Collation,ComparisonStyle,Edition,IsAnsiNullDefault,IsAnsiNullsEnabled,IsAnsiPaddingEnabled,IsAnsiWarningsEnabled,IsArithmeticAbortEnabled,IsAutoClose,IsAutoCreateStatistics,IsAutoCreateStatisticsIncremental,IsAutoShrink,IsAutoUpdateStatistics,IsClone,IsCloseCursorsOnCommitEnabled,IsFulltextEnabled,IsInStandBy,IsLocalCursorsDefault,IsMemoryOptimizedElevateToSnapshotEnabled,IsMergePublished,IsNullConcat,IsNumericRoundAbortEnabled,IsParameterizationForced,IsQuotedIdentifiersEnabled,IsPublished,IsRecursiveTriggersEnabled,IsSubscribed,IsSyncWithBackup,IsTornPageDetectionEnabled,IsVerifiedClone,IsXTPSupported,LastGoodCheckDbTime,LCID,MaxSizeInBytes,Recovery,ServiceObjective,ServiceObjectiveId,SQLSortOrder,Status,Updateability,UserAccess,Version'
,',') ss
```